# create-react-app script "start" vs manually typing in the command line behaves differently

Tags: reactjs, express, async-await, create-react-app

[image: e]

I have a create-react-app project with the "start" script as "nodemon backend/app.js". Both running yarn start (npm start) or manually typing cd backend --> nodemon app.js run the server fine. However, the script runs into an error when calling for requests whereas the manual option works fine. Any guidance or help would be appreciated. [image] The script option can't seem to retrieve the token whereas the manual option works fine.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "personal_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Personal website",
  "main": "src/components/App/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "format": "prettier \"src/**/*.{js,jsx, tsx}\" --write",
    "lint": "tslint --project",
    "dev": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
    "start": "nodemon backend/app.js",
    "predeploy": "yarn run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/wakoong/personal_website.git"
  },
  "author": "Woosik Koong <woosik.koong@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://woosika.com/"
  },
  "homepage": "https://wakoong.github.io/playground/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "react-table": "^6.10.3",
    "tslint": "^5.19.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-react": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.3.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/reach__router": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.2",
    "algotrader": "^2.4.9",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.0.4",
    "d3": "^5.12.0",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.20.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "marked": "^0.7.0",
    "mixin-deep": "^2.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.2.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.4",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "react": ">=15",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.4",
    "react-is": "^16.10.2",
    "react-markdown": "^4.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-window-size": "^1.2.2",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "reducers": "^3.0.0-alpha",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-api-middleware": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "robinhood": "^1.6.4",
    "safer-eval": "^1.3.5",
    "set-value": "^3.0.1",
    "store": "^2.0.12",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "warning": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "11.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: I've added my package.json. Thanks!

Comment: I've found out that process.env variables are undefined using yarn start but I am not sure as to why that is.

Comment: Where's the script option ? (package.json of the front)

Comment: I actually found the answer to my question. .env file should be located at the same level where the scripts is written (package.json). I had .env file inside my backend folder and that is why it worked fine when I ran the server manually but not via the start script. Thanks